# Invalid credential error on jenkins while pulling a github project

Tags: docker, jenkins, github

I have a Jenkins 2.150.1 in a docker container. To install this Jenkins I just use the `jenkinsci/blueocean:1.9.0` image.

I create a pipeline and then try to use my GitHub credential to do some jenkins stuff on a private repo. However, I got the following error:

```
Scan Repository Log

Started
[Thu Dec 13 15:09:49 GMT 2018] Starting branch indexing...
15:09:49 Connecting to https://api.github.com using Noon/****** (Another try)
ERROR: [Thu Dec 13 15:09:50 GMT 2018] Could not update folder level actions from source 7230f2ea-dac0-4018-819a-3bc105b6850f
hudson.AbortException: Invalid scan credentials when using Noon/****** (Another try) to connect to  Owner/Repo on https://api.github.com
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieveActions(GitHubSCMSource.java:1672)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:765)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:591)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:277)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:165)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1025)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
[Thu Dec 13 15:09:50 GMT 2018] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.5 sec
FATAL: Invalid scan credentials when using Noon/****** (Another try) to connect to  Owner/Repo on https://api.github.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thinking I had made an error with my credential, I re-entered it. And again. And again. I'm now quite convince that my credential are perfectly fine but that the problem is something else. I did find some old bug report with similar issue but the problem had long been fix.

Comment: I had this issue for several hours this morning on a new job and a new Jenkins instance, Credentials were definitely right as they were working for other jobs. Anyway I drop the credentials, recreated them and it fixed the issue, no idea about the root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I fixed this issue before posting this message, I have decided to post and self-answer it anyway because it was really tricky to figure.

## This isn't a logging problem, this a space problem!

When I specified where Jenkins should go to pull the sources, I entered the owner of the project, I entered " Owner" instead of "Owner". Jenkins did not complain and was still able to auto-complete the "Repo" part. The problem only occurred later and prompt this, very misleading, error message.

<sub>This is probably a bug that should be reported but I don't know where and how to do so.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The name I put in the "Owner" field was not valid, even though the repository drop down populated.

I updated to use the name of my organization (as per the GitHub url - https://github.com/{org name}/{repo}) and Jenkins was then able to scan the repo.

Next problem, the path to the jenkinsfile cannot start with a '/'.